# C++ : How to use SAPI with QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, sapi

I've got to do a project who consist to create a web browser including a Text To Speech solution. I've used examples from the MSDN ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720163(v=vs.85).aspx)), but when I try to compile my project, i've got a lot of errors, and I haven't found any solutions...

I'm using QT Creator for this project.

[The console output](http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2015/06/19/150619051022834686.png)

This is my project.pro :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-06-18T15:14:25
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += widgets webkitwidgets network multimedia

TARGET = Project

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    browser.cpp

HEADERS += \
    browser.h

unix|win32: LIBS += -lsapi
```

And my main.cpp :

```
#include <sapi.h>
#include "sphelper.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ISpVoice *pVoice;
    pVoice = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = SpCreateBestObject(SPCAT_VOICES, L”Gender=Female”, NULL, &pVoice); 
    // --> I tried with HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);, that's the same result...
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        hr = pVoice->Speak(L"Hello world", 0, NULL);
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the most simplistic example I can think of that will work for MSVC. I don't imagine it would be too much more different for QT Creator.

```
#include <sapi.h>
#include <sphelper.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> cpVoice;

    ::CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = cpVoice.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        cpVoice->Speak(L"This is a test phrase.", SPF_DEFAULT, NULL);
        cpVoice.Release();
    }

    puts("Press any key to continue...");
    getch();
}
```

This code will grab the default voice and start speaking. In Windows 7 that voice will be MS Anna.

Comment: Hello RobotScourge, Your example works correctly with QT Creator, Thanks a lot !